# Weird behaviour for event.target

Tags: javascript, html

I return here seeking an answer for my noob question. I am working with PHP, MySQL and JavaScript(AJAX as well) to make a categories menu which includes classes and subclasses taken from my MySQL database. I am inputting them with PHP, but in the Demo, I will use the final output. My problem is that i want to update the contents of the second submenu when hovering over a class. I want to display the second menu when hovering over the first(as a hole) and display the contents of the second one only when a class is hovered. To understand my situation better, this is my code:

```js
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

function deschid_subcat(subcat) {
  if (!httpRequest) {
    //alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = get_subcat;
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'get-subcat.php?q=' + subcat, true);
  httpRequest.send();

  function get_subcat() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('subclasa').innerHTML = this.responseText;
      } else {
        //alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }

}
window.onmousemove = function(event) {
  anim_subcat(event);
}

function anim_subcat(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('dropdown-content-categorii') || event.target == document.getElementById('subclase-content') || event.target == document.getElementById('grp')) {
    document.getElementById('subclase-content').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dropdown-content-categorii').style.boxShadow = "0px 5px 10px grey";
  } else if (event.target != document.getElementById('dropdown-content-categorii')) {
    document.getElementById('dropdown-content-categorii').style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 10px grey";
    document.getElementById('subclase-content').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.categorii {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: url('pictures/buton_categorii.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-categorii:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}

.dropdown-categorii {
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 11%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-categorii {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  animation-name: slideIn-categ;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
}

@keyframes slideIn-categ {
  from {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 38px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.dropdown-categorii:hover .dropdown-content-categorii {
  display: block;
}

.categoriesep {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes slideIn-categsep {
  from {
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 38px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#subclase-content {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 301px;
  margin-top: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px grey;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Ubuntu2;
  color: #003e91;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-name: subcat-ap;
}

@keyframes subcat-ap {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 295px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 301px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-categorii">
  <button class="categorii" id="categorii">CATEGORII</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content-categorii" id="dropdown-content-categorii" style="box-shadow: grey 5px 5px 10px;">
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=AMBALARE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("AMBALARE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">AMBALARE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=CHIMICE++SI+TEHNICE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("CHIMICE++SI+TEHNICE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">CHIMICE  SI TEHNICE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=CONSTRUCTII"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("CONSTRUCTII")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">CONSTRUCTII</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ELECTRICE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("ELECTRICE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ELECTRICE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=INSTALATII+SANITARE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("INSTALATII+SANITARE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">INSTALATII SANITARE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=INSTALATII+TERMICE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("INSTALATII+TERMICE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">INSTALATII TERMICE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=ORGANE+DE+ANSAMBLARE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("ORGANE+DE+ANSAMBLARE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">ORGANE DE ANSAMBLARE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SCULE%2CUNELTE%2CACCESORII"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("SCULE%2CUNELTE%2CACCESORII")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SCULE UNELTE ACCESORII</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=SISTEME+DE+FIXARE"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("SISTEME+DE+FIXARE")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">SISTEME DE FIXARE</button></a>
    <a id="grp" href="http://localhost/prod.php?categ=TAMPLARIE+PVC+SI+ALUMINIU"><button onmouseover='deschid_subcat("TAMPLARIE+PVC+SI+ALUMINIU")' class="categoriesep" id="categoriesep">TAMPLARIE PVC SI ALUMINIU</button></a>
  </div>
  <div id="subclase-content" class="subclase-content" style="display: none;">
    <p id="subclasa" style="margin-left: 4px;">
      <p id="cls"> PLASE INSECTE</p>
      <p id="cls">FERESTRE PVC SI ALUMINIU</p>
      <p id="cls">FERONERIE PVC SI ALUMINIU</p>
      <p id="cls">PLASE INSECTE</p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The AJAX Code works fine and retrieves the subclasses just fine from the database( in the demo, it is only shown on of the subclasses since i can't get ajax fully working in this snippet. so, the acutal subclass won't update and be the same). My problem is on the second part of the Javascript code. I thought that if i check everytime the mousemoves on the window if it is in a different location other then `dropdown-content-categorii` and the second menu, it wouldn't trigger the `else if` and wouldn't close my menu. But, the text is a different object(to call it like that) and such, it will close the submenu. My noobness comes in here, because i can't get the submenu to remain visible when having the cursor over the text. It is like the cursor ignores the text.I have tried by setting the last condition in the `if` for the `grp` elements, but it doesn't work.

Thank you for reading my long post and i hope it isn't confusing. I'd like to hear your suggestions and advice!

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS `:hover` instead of constantly running (relatively intensive) code every time the mouse moves by a pixel?

Comment: Could i use hover for the whole menu? Will it still update the contents of the submenu? I honestly haven't give much thought to CSS when thinking about the menu. I'll try to see if i can make something out of the idea, but i'd really like to know why the javascript code won't run as it should?